Is there a way to serialize the name of an interface in java using Json?
Here's what i'm trying to do in Java using Jackson. I have an interface AstronomicalBody which have two classes implementing it; Planet and Star. When i'm serialising the two classes implementing the interface, i want the interface to be written something like this:
{
   "AstronomicalBody" : {
      //Planet.class or Star.class fields
   }
}

OR
{
   "entity" : "AstronomicalBody"
   "details" : {
      //Planet.class or Star.class fields
   }
}

I've tried different annotations but i can't get it to work.

Does this answer your question? Deserialize JSON with Jackson into Polymorphic Types - A Complete Example is giving me a compile error

@Chaosfire No, that's the opposite of what i'm trying to do. I don't want "Dog" to be written. I instead want "Animal" to be written in both the Dog and the Cat cases.

Just change the name to whatever you need then - @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Interface").  But this is starting to look like a XY problem, it makes no sense to serialize useless information. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Another issue i forgot to mention, after testing this solution, is that i don't have access to Dog/Cat.class due to circular dependencies.

Although the question seems a bit incomplete, I would advise you not to try to tweak the mappings to that level of detail; you will probably end up with something complex and fragile. Instead, create DTOs that serialize as needed; e.g. for the second alternative, a class like class X { String entity; AstronomicalBody details }. For the first, maybe @JsonRootName will do.

What do you mean with “i don't have access to Dog/Cat.class due to circular dependencies”?! What do dogs and cats have to do with astronomical bodies? And in case, you actually mean Planet and Star, how can you not have access to them when you are about to serialize instances of them?

@Holger cats and dogs are from the other question Chaosfire linked to.
